# LSTM data structure

Tags: neural-networks, panel-data, missing-data, lstm

I'm trying to predict trade international flows between countries using LSTM Neural Nets for which I have a panel structured data set with country-pair-year observations $x_{i, j, t}$. Given a  `lookback` period, I would have to specify the "lagged" periods $t-1, t-2$ until $t-$`lookback` for each pair $i, j$ in a year $t$. However, some of the country-pairs have missing years (maybe because they just didn't trade that year, or it wasn't recorded). Should I be filling up the missing datapoints with `NA` until the observation is `lookback` long?

Comment: If A and B didn't trade during a year, then the value of their trade is 0, right? This doesn't resolve the [tag:missing-data] question, though, which is perhaps the larger problem.

Comment: Correct. I'm training a separate network to determine whether a country-pair did indeed trade or not, but that is a different problem.